# ASP.NET output caching anonymous users only

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Is it possible to only output cache pages which are being viewed by an anonymous user?

My homepage is `default.aspx`. I would only want an anonymous user to be served from the cache. If a logged in user viewed it, I would want the page to hit the server.

I know you can partially cache pages but I would rather keep it simple.